# How to get ASP Classic IF to check for empty or NULL values on multiple columns

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

In a MS SQL table I have 4 columns that can have 3 different values of (`yes`, `empty` or `NULL`), in these 4 columns I need to check with ASP Classic if they are all either empty or NULL.

I.e I have Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4, and if they all are either empty or NULL (or different from `yes`) it should write something to the screen, so I have tried to do this with the following:

```vb
<% IF objFlowVAR("Col1") = "" OR IsNull(objFlowVAR("Col1")) AND objFlowVAR("Col2") = "" OR IsNull(objFlowVAR("Col2")) AND objFlowVAR("Col3") = "" OR IsNull(objFlowVAR("Col3")) AND objFlowVAR("Col4") = "" OR IsNull(objFlowVAR("Col4")) THEN %>Some Text<% END IF %>
```

```vb
<% IF objFlowVAR("Col1") <> "yes" AND objFlowVAR("Col2") <> "yes" AND objFlowVAR("Col3") <> "yes" AND objFlowVAR("Col4") <> "yes" THEN %>Some Text<% END IF %>
```

But this is not given me the result I need.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Null` and `DbNull` are different so don’t expect `IsNull()` to behave as you expect.

I’ve found the best approach is the sanitise the values first;

```vb
Dim col1, col2, col3, col4
col1 = objFlowVAR("Col1") & ""
col2 = objFlowVAR("Col2") & ""
col3 = objFlowVAR("Col3") & ""
col4 = objFlowVAR("Col4") & ""
If Len(col1) = 0 And Len(col2) = 0 And Len(col3) = 0 And Len(col4) = 0 Then
  'All values are empty, so do sonething.
End If
```

Comment: Thank you @user692942 that worked perfectly, although `>` should be changed to `=` to fit my purpose :-)

Comment: @StigKølbæk sorry was writing on my mobile have corrected it. You could also have wrapped the statements in a `Not (....)` to reverse the outcome as well which is what I missed while typing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need to do one thing if it is null and another if it is not null, but using what user692942's method of instead of doing `IsNull()` and just checking length to see if its greater than 0 is indeed the best way to do this, especially if you are only dealing with 'yes' as the only string.  If you did have other options than just yes later, breaking it out into parts like I show below might be useful to you, but I based it off his example above so you would need to use the dims and same variable settings of course.  You can even do nested IF/THEN's if you must, but it is more efficient to use `CASE SELECT` if you have more elaborate combinations of outcomes.  But on to the code:

```
    IF Len(col1) > 0  Then
      'col1 is NOT NULL
    ELSE
      'col1 is NULL
    END IF
```

You could get one perfect with the code in place for each if it is null and it isn't null situation, then copy that and past it 3 more times, and just change the numbers on the other 3 to be col2 and col3 and so forth, but would be easy to get the whole thing in place fast if this is what you need instead.

Since someone saw this useful I thought I would cover a CASE SELECT too just in "CASE" there is need for more advanced logic, such as if it might matter if it was NULL versus '' empty or different string types, as well as a default everything else catcher, very handy stuff for this sort of thing.

```
Select Case col1
   Case col1 = "" : 'code to do when its actually empty
   Case col1 = Len(col1) > 0 AND col1 <> "" : 'code to do when its NULL
   Case col1 = "yes" :  'code to do when its set to 'yes'
   Case col1 = "no" :  'code to do when its set to 'no'
Case Else
   'code to do when everything else not defined happens
End Select
```

The 'code to do parts are just comment lines that you would replace everything from the ' after it with the ASP code you want to happen what that case triggers.

Comment: That `Select` statement looks wrong to me.

Comment: You are right, my apologize was working in MYSQL at the time I wrote that and slipped my mind, you do want to use "" for this.  I replaced them just now.

Comment: I think it should be fine now, but the second case with the AND is the only one I worry about throwing an error.  Its going to be a couple days before I can get back to my test environment for ASP so my apologies, but I will keep up with the thread until then.